# Linear Algebra: the big picture

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to solve some types of equations now, but I'm still having trouble seeing the big picture to all of this.

For example, I understand how to implement Gaussian elimination, but I have trouble explaining why it works as a method for solving systems of linear equations.

Or why is the linear independence important when looking at spanning sets?

Is there any case where you know (without row-reducing) that a homogenous system is guaranteed to have a non-trival solution?

Also, I know the procedure for determining the inverse of a matrix, but don't really understand why it might not produce and inverse for some matrix.

Could someone please clarify?

Much thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guernica_%28painting%29

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Supper_%28da_Vinci%29

Comment: @WillJagy I'm actually somewhat jealous of your brilliant comment. OP asks to see the 'big picture' and you reference the Last Supper. Nothing better than meaningful answer disguised as a cheap pun.

Comment: @muros Most students wouldn't expected to get the 'big picture' of linear algebra at this stage in your education. In you're question, you talked a lot about systems of equations, ways to solve them, etc. As far as I'm considered you haven't encountered linear algebra yet, so no wonder you have no idea what it's about. So far you've only been taught to parrot some very important applications of linear algebra, intended to motivate the introduction of abstract vector spaces. That's the point where linear algebra begins.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185766/ for suggestions of advanced linear algebra textbooks.